# c# XNA 2d vector points relative to origin

Tags: c#, vector, xna, rotation, 2d

I have a query on manipulating Vectors in c# XNA. I currently have a 2d texture with an origin set to the centre of the sprite, and two separate vectors that are relative to that origin, like so:

```
ship1.Engine1.X = (float)Math.Cos(ship1.Angle) * 50 + ship1.Position.X;
ship1.Engine1.Y = (float)Math.Sin(ship1.Angle) * 50 + ship1.Position.Y;
ship1.Engine2.X = (float)Math.Cos(ship1.Angle) * -50 + ship1.Position.X;
ship1.Engine2.Y = (float)Math.Sin(ship1.Angle) * -50 + ship1.Position.Y;
```

Both of these engine vectors have particle effects for rockets, and so need to be positioned over the exhausts on the sprite. They are lined up along the relative X axis of the ship texture, but I cannot work out the math behind moving them downwards, in the relative y axis. How would I go about doing that?  Thanks in advance.

What I mean: https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5bkS.png

Comment: Please show the code where you manipulate the orientation of the particle effects (what you have now). You are just showing the positions above. How is orientation defined in `Engine1` and `Engine2` ?

Comment: Please clarify: you have positioned the emitters correctly, but you want the particles to move in `ship1.Angle-180`?

Comment: @annonymously: Close but Math.Cos and Math.Sin take radians, and 180 degrees will still put it on the same axis, just opposite sides. I believe he'll need to replace ship1.Angle with either ship1.Angle + MathHelper.PiOver2 or ship1.Angle - MathHelper.PiOver2.

Comment: This is the manipulation. The particle effect is mapped to engine1 and engine2 (both vectors) exactly. The angle is in radians, that's not the problem. This works, but I need to add to it. I've added an image to show what I mean.

Comment: ...and I've just realised what you were all saying. Multiplying the angle by the extra radians was exactly what I needed to do, and trying it worked brilliantly. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You're welcome. I will put it as an answer so it will no longer show up in the unanswered section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're giving the points the same rotation as the ship.

Try replacing `ship1.Angle` with either `ship1.Angle + MathHelper.PiOver2` or `ship1.Angle - MathHelper.PiOver2`